# How to generate component.json from package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, bower

I install es5-shim with bower correctly with:

```
bower install es5-shim
```

But it doesn't include a main file, so when listing the sources I get an empty list:

```
bower list --sources
{}
```

I've looked into [es5-shim repo](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) and it just has a [package.json](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/blob/master/package.json) which includes a definition for "main": "es5-shim.js"

How is the component.json generated?

It seems to miss the main attribute. This is the [component.json](https://gist.github.com/pdjota/5245648) I get in the components/es5-shim when installing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bower doesn't use package.json. Bower will fall back and generate a component.json from the repo name and git tag version when a repo doesn't have a component.json, which is why it doesn't have a `main` attribute.

Comment: Ok, but the problem I see is that I need the main attribute. Should I modify the Package.prototype.generateAssetJSON https://github.com/twitter/bower/blob/master/lib/core/package.js#L240 ?

Comment: Best solution right now would be to fork it, modify and tag it.